# How to add on to formatted date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

this is what I have got:

```
$_SESSION["chosen_exam_start_time"] = new DateTime();
$schedule_date =  $_SESSION["chosen_exam_start_time"]; 
$schedule_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$triggerOn =  $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

so I have a date passed within the session called "chosen_exam_start_time".

Now what I am struggling to do is add on $triggerOn.

So currently if I do

```
die(var_dump($triggerOn));
```

I get :

```
string(19) "2016-03-28 17:17:57"
```

What I want to do is if I have another variable which tells me a value like 10, how would I be able to add that value on to the $triggerOn. So that it will be:

```
string(19) "2016-03-28 17:27:57"
```

What I have done up to now is :

```
            $_SESSION["chosen_exam_start_time"] = new DateTime();
            $schedule_date =  $_SESSION["chosen_exam_start_time"]; 
            $schedule_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
            $triggerOn =  $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $value = 10;

            $triggerOn->modify((int) $value.' minute');


            die(var_dump($triggerOn));
```

However this die is not printing anything out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doesn't make sense to make any sort of calculation using strings. Just imagine you had this:

```
$price = 'Thirty five point nine';
$discount = 'Twenty percent';
```

... and you wanted to apply the discount ;-)

If your current architecture makes it impossible to keep the original DateTime object (I don't know, I don't have enough information for that) you'd better create a new one:

```
<?php

$triggerOn = '2016-03-28 17:17:57';
$minutes_to_add = 10;

$triggerOnDateTime = new DateTime($triggerOn, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$triggerOnDateTime->modify( sprintf('%d minutes', $minutes_to_add) );
$triggerOn = $triggerOnDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the modify function on a datetime object.

```
$trigger->modify((int) $value.' minute');
```

Note I just pulled this from the [Carbon Library](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), which is a very useful wrapper for DateTime giving you a good bit of syntactic sugar such as:

```
$trigger->addMinutes(10);
```

Comment: $_SESSION["chosen_exam_start_time"] = new DateTime();
                $schedule_date =  $_SESSION["chosen_exam_start_time"]; 
                $schedule_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
                $triggerOn =  $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $value = 10;
                
                $triggerOn->modify((int) $value.' minute');


                die(var_dump($triggerOn));

Comment: I have tried this but the die is not printing anything out now

Comment: I have updated my question to show it clearly, thanks